# Odata type converting URL

Tags: datetime, odata, breeze

I am new to odata and trying some things at the moment. I want to offer a Method with 2 parameters of type DateTime. I tried to send a request by url and it didn't work. Can somebody give me any advise what I am doing wrong?

```
 [HttpGet]
 public IQueryable<TestData> TestMethod([FromUri]  DateTime dateFrom, [FromUri]  DateTime dateTo)
 {
    ...
 }
```

My Request: data/ManagementReporting/TestMethod?dateFrom=datetime'2014-02-01'&dateTo=datetime'2014-04-01'

Answer (score 1):

You can reference `http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/creating-an-odata-endpoint` to build a OData endpoint in Webapi.
In your case, first, you can define the `TestMethod` as an unbound function in the EdmModel by:

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
var functionConfiguration = builder.Function("TestMethod");
functionConfiguration.Parameter<DateTime>("dateFrom");
functionConfiguration.Parameter<DateTime>("dateTo");
```

And then, try the query as Maya said. You can also reference [OData Protocol](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-os-part1-protocol.html#_Toc372793741) to find more info about how to call a function in OData. 
Otherwise, [http://www.odata.org](http://www.odata.org/) is a great website if you want to know more about odata.

Answer (score 0):

the request is URL is wrong.
If you want to call the function and pass the parameter, please try:

data/ManagementReporting/TestMethod(dataFrom='2014-02-01',dataTo='2014-04-01')

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default breeze WebApi/WebApi2 controller and if you want to pass arbitrary parameters to the server, you can do something like this:

- On the client

  ```
  var q = EntityQuery.from("EmployeesFilteredByCountryAndBirthdate")
      .withParameters({ birthDate: "1/1/1960", country: "USA" });

  em.executeQuery(q).then(function (data) { ... }
  ```
- On the server

  ```
  [HttpGet]
  public IQueryable<Employee> EmployeesFilteredByCountryAndBirthdate(DateTime birthDate, string country) {
    return ContextProvider.Context.Employees.Where(
      emp => emp.BirthDate >= birthDate && emp.Country == country);
  }
  ```